# Apply geometry node on curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I ve been trying to create a set of verticies on a curve with a uniform distance in Blender. After failing with having the curve represented as a mesh,i ve found out that the curve has precisely the node i need - Curve to Point. However, when I try to apply it, so i can work with those newly created points I get an error.
[image]

So the question is - can I somehow "export" those newly created points or apply the modifier?

Thanks!
Adam

Comment: Historically blender never allowed applying constructive modifiers on curve objects, as far as I know. Possible workarounds are exporting as mesh instead, then manually convert to curve afterwards; export as points; or instance something like an empty on them, realize instances, then manually reconstruct a curve from those objects.

Comment: Object > Convert > Mesh is what you're after I think

Comment: Thank you guys. At the end, I used the Convert > Mesh approach, and then in Geometry Nodes I used Curve to Points.